# Grub black screen on external hdd

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive

I have a HP Pavilion dv6 laptop with HD Radeon and with W7 preinstalled in a internal hdd.

I try to install ubuntu in a external hdd, but the Grub don't load, only appear a black screen and i only can to power off the laptop.
If i change the hdd's, W7 can load from the external hdd and ubuntu works fine from the internal hdd.

Whats happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you physically switching two harddrives around, one connected internally (through SATA?), and one connected externally (through USB/eSATA?), or have you installed Ubuntu on the two different harddrives, and it only works on one of them?

Comment: Yes i switching the harddrives. Internal is SATA and external is connected from USB.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu did you install? Did you have the harddrive connected internally or externally when you installed it? Do you know if you installed GRUB for EFI or BIOS and did you do any manual partitioning?

Comment: Version is Ubuntu 15.10. 
I had connected externaly when i installed it. 
I don't know the GRUB is for EFI or BIOS. 
And yes I made the partition manually

Comment: What is the output of cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep "menuentry 'Ubuntu'" -A 15 ?

Comment: I put the result as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is the output of cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep "menuentry 'Ubuntu'" -A 15

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-26e384d0-b064-49c9-98a1-dd92bdfc8174' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,msdos8'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos8 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos8 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos8  3d95e70d-8342-4c37-bf28-53e843f66a22
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3d95e70d-8342-4c37-bf28-53e843f66a22
        fi
        linux   /vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic root=UUID=26e384d0-b064-49c9-98a1-dd92bdfc8174 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        initrd  /initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
```